# Replace every letter with its position in the alphabet for a given string

Tags: c++, string, function, replace, alphabet

The first step, I changed the string to a lowercase, after that I removed all the non letters from the string, now I am struggling to replace each letter with the alphabet position.
does anyone know how to do such a thing?
Thank you!

```cpp
string alphabet_position(string message){
   string alphabet= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   int aplha_numbers[100];

 for_each(message.begin(), message.end(), [](char & c){
     c = ::tolower(c);
 });

 for(int i=0; i< message.size(); i++){

     if(message[i] < 'a' || message[i] > 'z'){
         message.erase(i, 1);
         i--;
     }
 }
for(int j=0; j<message.size(); j++){
    int index = alphabet.find(message[j]);
     aplha_numbers[j]= index +1;


}
std::ostringstream os;
for(int z: aplha_numbers){
    os<<z;
}
std::string str(os.str());

return str;
}
```

Now I have a different issue , I am getting the alphabet positions but I also get a lot of garbage values after the last letter.
As an example Input: abc
output 123 and after that a lot of numbers 32761004966.....

Comment: Since there are 26 letters in the English alphabet, replacing characters with their numbers will not be a 1:1 ratio.  I recommend creating a new string with the index numbers.  See `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: What's the difficulty level in pasting code as text instead of pictures?  I thought it was easy.

Comment: The number of the letter is given by: `number = letter - 'a';`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews — there is nothing in C++ that guarantees that `letter - ‘a’` will work. On a system that uses EBCDIC it will be wrong. For ASCII it works, but unless you know what encoding is being used, getting the position in the alphabet of a letter requires a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your comments, I changed my approach a bit, but I am facing a different issue now. I updated the code. @ThomasMatthews2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are a few issues in your code:**

1. Your main bug was that in this line:

   `for (int z : aplha_numbers)`

   You go over all the 100 elements in the allocated array, not just the valid entries.
   In my solution there's no need for such an array at all. The `stringstream` objec is updated directly.
2. The position of a lower case character `c` is simply `c-'a'+1`. No need for a lookup table (at least assuming ascii input).
3. There's no need to actually change the input string by making it a lower case. This can be done on the fly as you traverse it.

**Here's a complete fixed version:**

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

std::string alphabet_position(std::string message) 
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    for (auto const & c : message)
    {
        char c_lower = std::tolower(c);
        if (c_lower < 'a' || c_lower > 'z')  continue;
        int pos = c_lower - 'a' + 1;
        os << pos;
    }
    return os.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string s_in = "AbC";
    std::string s_out = alphabet_position(s_in);
    std::cout << "in:" << s_in << ", out:" << s_out << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
in:AbC, out:123
```

**A side note:** it's better to avoid `using namespace std;`. See here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)